# Can I translate a geojson file into rasterized tiles for consumption by leaflet?

Tags: c#, image-processing, geojson

I built a very simple map tile server that serves up pre-rendered, rasterized map tiles and is used in conjunction with leaflet:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTile(int z, int x, int y)
    {
        var mainFolder = "C:\\maptiles\\";
        var image = System.IO.File.OpenRead(mainFolder + string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}.png", z, x, y));
        return File(image, "image/png");
    }
```

I now need to create a separate endpoint that will send dynamically generated bitmap tiles back to the client based on a geojson file instead of the pre-rendered bitmaps. Something like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetGeoJsonTile(int z, int x, int y)
    {
        var geoJsonFilePath = "C:\\geojsontiles\\coverage-area.geojson";
        var geoJsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(geoJsonFilePath));
        Byte[] imageBytes;

        //RASTERIZE ENTIRE GEOJSON TO BITMAP HERE
        //...

        //CROP AND ZOOM RASTERIZED BITMAP TO FIT x,y,z PARAMS
        //...

        return File(imageBytes, "image/png");
    }
```

The rasterize piece should be fairly simple (I think). But the part that I am getting hung up on is the cropping and zooming. I understand that a geojson file is essentially a vector map with references to lat/lon coordinates. I don't understand how those lat/lon coordinates translate to the x,y,z coordinates that are input based on the user's interaction with the map on the client side. Is there a way that I can use the lat/lon information inside the geojson file in conjunction with the x,y,z inputs to determine how far to zoom, and where to crop the output rasterized image?

Also, I do realize that leaflet (and other clients) support geojson files directly. But that is not an option for me. The geojson files we are using are very large and complex and cause major lagging issues when used on client machines.

Comment: Did you find any good solution? I have exactly the same problem now

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer: look into the XYZ and TMS tile numbering schemes

If you're using Leaflet to display a tiled map, I'm assuming you're using the [`L.tileLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer) object. That being the case, the actual coordinates corresponding to the `(x, y, z)` tuple are given by the ["XYZ standard"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map) (or by  the [TMS standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service) if you set `tms: true`, which just flips the `y` axis).

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map#Defining_a_tiled_web_map), the basic idea behind this tile system is this:

- Tiles are 256x256 pixels
- At the outer most zoom level, 0, the entire world can be rendered in a single map tile.
- Each zoom level doubles in both dimensions, so a single tile is replaced by 4 tiles when zooming in. This means that about 22 zoom levels are sufficient for most practical purposes.
- The Web Mercator projection is used, with latitude limits of around 85 degrees.

[The OpenStreetMap Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Implementations) contains math formulas to calculate the corresponding coordinate window of a tile, as well as sample implementations in several programming languages, including C#.

## But look into using an existing solution instead

There is a limited number of scenarios in which "hand-making" the tile cutting code would make sense. If you can, try to use the [`gdal2tiles.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html) command from the GDAL library (and its accompanying CLI commands) by calling it from your C# code. You may also consider hosting the tiles directly in a separate "geospatial server" such as [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) instead.